# How to extract values based on column header in excel?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, excel, lookup-tables

I have an excel file containing values, I needed values as the highlighted one in single column and deleting the rest on. But due to mismatch in rows and column header file, I am not able to extract. Once you will see the excel will able to understand what values I needed.As this is just a sample of mine data.

1. Column A2:A17 date is continuous but few date are repeating, but in Row (D1:K1) date are not repeating, so in this case value of same date occurring just below of of one other.
2. How to get values in one column?
3. Is there a way to highlight the values of same date occurring in row and column? The sample data consist of manually highlighted. I have huge dataset that cannot be manually highlighted.
4. Because from colour code also I can get the required values too.

Following is the file I am attaching here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-xBMKRP1_toA_Ky8mKxCKAFi4uQ8YWJq/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110042758694954349181&rtpof=true&sd=true

Please visit the link and help me to find the solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what those values in columns D to K are.

If only the shaded ones matter and they can be derived from the Latitude and Longitude for each row separately:

Insert a column titled "Row", say in A, and populate it 1,2,3...
I think you also want a column E which is whatever the calculation you currently have in D-K. Is this "Distance"?

Then create a Pivot Table on rows A to E and you can do anything you are likely to need: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576
Dates at Colum Labels, Row numbers as Row Labels, and Sum of "Distance" as Values.